# add listener to page refresh event

Tags: events, primefaces

I have an action that needs to happen after the page is refreshed

(not necessarily by pressing F5 but any time the page has been refreshed).

How to add such event listener?

Answer (score 0):

I use this:

```
<h:form>
   <p:remoteCommand name="update_page" process="@this" update="form" actionListener="#{myView.myAction}" />
.
.
.
.
</h:form>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    update_page();
  }
 </script>
```

Load or refresh of page run *RemoteCommand*.

Comment: Why not add an `autorun="true"` to the `p:remoteCommand`? Works the same, less code

Comment: Yes, it's true. I use embed the call to remoteCommand into _$(document).ready()_ to manage a modal splash screen